# Trouble Initializing Contract with Lists

Tags: michelson, origination

I am trying to learn smart contracts on Tezos and decided to originate my own. The contract is expecting the following storage:

```
pair (pair (address %owner)
             (list %received
                (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %sendr) (int %threadID))))
       (list %sent
          (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %receiver) (int %threadID)))
```

I then tried to initialize the contract with empty lists but continuously get the ill typed data error:

```
Ill typed data:
  1: (pair (pair (address "tz1dzhKD21HWFgEHqB1BiY4BoTWoDa7y6i77") (list {})) (list {}))
is not an expression of type
  pair (pair (address %owner)
             (list %received
                (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %sendr) (int %threadID))))
       (list %sent
          (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %receiver) (int %threadID)))
At line 1 characters 0 to 80, value
  (pair (pair (address "tz1dzhKD21HWFgEHqB1BiY4BoTWoDa7y6i77") (list {})) (list {}))
is invalid for type
  pair (pair (address %owner)
             (list %received
                (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %sendr) (int %threadID))))
       (list %sent
          (pair (pair (timestamp %expiration) (string %hash)) (string %receiver) (int %threadID))).
At line 1 characters 0 to 80,
unexpected type name pair, only a constant constructor can be used here.
Fatal error:
  origination simulation failed
```

I have tried initializing it with various different inputs but can't seem to get it right.

```
./tezos-client -E https://testnet-tezos.giganode.io  originate contract test_contract transferring 0 from test_wallet running ~/contract.tz -D --init 'pair (pair (address "tz1dzhKD21HWFgEHqB1BiY4BoTWoDa7y6i77") (list {})) (list {})'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Pair (Pair "tz1dzhKD21HWFgEHqB1BiY4BoTWoDa7y6i77" {}) {})
```